# Google API document header

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-docs, google-docs-api

I have a node.js app and use docs_v1 from googleapis to create a document

```
const createdDoc = await docs.create({
    requestBody: { title }
});
```

and after that batchUpdate to fill with data.

```
await docs.batchUpdate({
    documentId: createdDoc.documentId,
    requestBody: {
        requests: [
            {
                insertText: {
                    location: {
                        index: 1
                    },
                    text: 'Some very important data in body of a document'
                }
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

Everything went well till I received a requirement to add some link into the header of a document.
[image with example of header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VutB5.jpg)
I tried dozen of approaches\request to create segment and add text, but I didn't meet any success.

If someone faced with such an issue and resolve this problem - please, share snippet of the request.

Comment: About `I tried dozen of approaches\request to create segment and add text, but I didn't meet any success.`, I cannot understand about your goal. I apologize for my poor English skill. Can I ask you about the detail of your goal?

Comment: @Tanike thank you for your question. On batchUpdate I tried in requestBody in requests array firstly use  createHeader command, then createNamedRange, and insert text in header and body segment.  (this all commands in the same payload)

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. From your replying, I understood your trying. But, unfortunately, from your replying, I cannot understand about your goal. Can I ask you about the detail of your goal?

Answer (score 0):

### You need to perform two requests to complete the process:

1. [insertText](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/request#inserttextrequest) to insert the text itself
2. [UpdateTextStyle](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/request#updatetextstylerequest) to convert the text into a hyperlink

Sample:

```
{
  "requests": [
    {
      "insertText": {
        "location": {
          "index": 1
        },
        "text": "google.com"
      }
    },
    {
      "updateTextStyle": {
        "textStyle": {
          "link": {
            "url": "https://www.google.com"
          }
        },
        "range": {
          "startIndex": 1,
          "endIndex": 11
        },
        "fields": "link"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```